# Printing image via wifi printer from my Android App

Tags: javascript, c#, android, unity-game-engine, printing

I have created a native plugin for my unity app, I want to be able to print from my app.

So far I have everything set up and performing simple functions however I now want to set up a print function (java), I've been reading up some documentation online however I seem to be missing something

"MyPrintDocumentAdapter" is returning an error of Cannot resolve symbol is there something else I need to add to the script or something else I can try?

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;


public class printclass extends Activity {


public void doPhotoPrint() {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) printclass.this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
        String jobName = printclass.this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
        // to handle the generation of a print document
        printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(printclass.this),
                null); //
```